# logic behind catching a variable

Tags: php, mysql, variables, logic

i would like to check if an user has made changes of a specific field when he fills out a form. in that form it will be echoed the old entry that comes from the db. clearly the variable that will be posted is:

```
$var = $_POST['var'];
```

the variable that will echo the entry of the db is:

```
echo $var
```

i look for some logic that means like:

```
$newvar = is the new entry that is not the old $var;
```

after the user has submit the form all new and "old" data will be stored in a second table. now my question is, how can i check if a field has new input or is it the same and in case of a new entry how to put this into a variable?

thanks.

**UPDATE**

okay, first of all thanks for answering. please do not tell me how to store data in a db or session. i'm looking for a code to realize. like i wrote i have the data stored into a second table! i dont know how to check each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this in two ways:

1. Check old values in the database after the form is submitted, and update accordingly.
   Simply query the database and compare the values in the DB vs $_POST
2. Pass the old values via a hidden input (I would not suggest this as the user can change the data)

Comment: this near to an solution. the form also will be posted via email to my mailaccount so that i can see the data. i like to compare them in the mail like: userid wants to change: $var  into  $newvar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep state in your app. You could use SESSION or a database. See http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Introduction-to-Maintaining-the-State-of-Applications-with-PHP-Sessions/